# How to verify the index on a table was created "Concurrently"

Tags: postgresql, index, concurrency

Normally after I create an index, I check pgAdmin to verify that the index was created correctly. However, I'm not sure how to verify if the "concurrently" argument I passed in went through since I don't see it listed in the SQL Pane as I do with the other properties I've specified. Please help. Currently using version 1.22.1 connected to a PostgreSQL 9.5 server.

Answer (score 1):

You would know that the index was created concurrently by observing the level of the lock on held on the table while the index was being built.

Once the index creation is done with, it is just an ordinary index.  Building an index concurrently is not an ongoing property of the index.